# GeoServer WMTS WKB error when QGIS reads PostGIS fine

Tags: geoserver, wmts, well-known-binary

Is there some problem that can make PostGIS point geometry unreadable by GeoServer WMTS? The points are generated with `st_makepoint` with lon/lat float args.

I'm especially confused because I have [other layers](https://geo.hyphae.design/geoserver/gwc/demo/stream:gh_19summ_garmin_pspnet?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile) that work fine.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: An exception occurred while parsing WKB data org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: An exception occurred while parsing WKB data An exception occurred while parsing WKB data Unknown WKB type 77

https://geo.hyphae.design/geoserver/stream/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=stream%3Asbir_sid_f5ck5f8hwjibdgpmuck6&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

[image: pgadmin query result]

```
"0101000020E6100000A59849E0237255C0EB43A5DF7F194340"
"0101000020E610000079686721247255C0968E24FB79194340"
"0101000020E61000003D31E96B247255C0951046B274194340"
"0101000020E6100000360300AA247255C0E7FCE14A70194340"
"0101000020E6100000328F64D3247255C0C8EF495B6D194340"
"0101000020E61000008956934CF37155C019ED4CFCAC194340"
"0101000020E6100000F1FE97ABEE7155C057CF52977C194340"
"0101000020E61000003B2A2E7FF07155C006EAB3A87C194340"
"0101000020E6100000ADCDB51EF47155C09CB92CCB7C194340"
"0101000020E61000001000BADBF77155C09B1B27CF7C194340"
```

[image: geometry as text]

Comment: Geoserver doesn't handle that type of wkb geometry.

Comment: @IanTurton OK so what is type 77 anyway and why is st_makepoint creating that type instead of a simple point?

Comment: Please post one such WKB string.

Comment: No idea what type 77 is as far as I know there are only 25 types (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) - the link you include works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I believe I resolved this problem. The issue was that the table was being created without an id primary key. The database was using the geom column as the PK because it was first in the data insert.

The fix was to delete the primary key constraint, add an auto-increment id integer column and make it the primary key. I then updated the layer in geoserver by using the 'reload geometry type' and the data began to be served correctly.